# ListView в DrawerFragment. Как изменить цвет выделенного Item?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. 
Такое дело, есть Drawer activity, где, как и положено, выезжающий список представлен listview. Я пытаюсь изменить его отображение так, что выбранный пункт списка будет выделен другим цветом, для этого вешаю на Listview селектор, для которого создаю в drawable нужные файлы, текст селектора ниже.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_map_item_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_map_item_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_map_item" />`
```

Запускаю приложение и вижу, что обычное состояние item'a, описанное в селекторе, применилось, а выбранный элемент остается родного цвета. Как быть, где я не прав? Вот скрин https://yadi.sk/i/1Hb3bbu3cJGHG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в теме у активити задать:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/{selector}</item> </style>
```

Comment: В общем, помогло частично. Теперь у меня нет выделения выбранного элемента цветом, просто background реагирует на нажатие и меняет цвет, что тоже хорошо.

Comment: @Sharlei добавьте еще `android:state_selected="true"` и `android:state_activated="true"`